# Python module: Trouble Installing Bitarray 0.8.0 on Mac OSX 10.7.4

Tags: python, gcc

I have trouble installing `bitarray` (vers 0.8.0) on my Mac OSX 10.7.4. Thanks!

`gcc` does not seem to be the problem:

```
Last login: Sun Sep  9 22:24:25 on ttys000
host-001:~ gabriele$ gcc -version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
host-001:~ gabriele$ 

Last login: Sun Sep  9 22:18:41 on ttys000
host-001:~ gabriele$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitarray-0.8.0/
host-001:bitarray-0.8.0 gabriele$ python2.7 setup.py installrunning install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating bitarray.egg-info
writing bitarray.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to bitarray.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to bitarray.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'bitarray.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'bitarray.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'bitarray.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/bitarray
copying bitarray/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/bitarray
copying bitarray/test_bitarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/bitarray
running build_ext
building 'bitarray._bitarray' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/bitarray
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c bitarray/_bitarray.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/bitarray/_bitarray.o
unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
host-001:bitarray-0.8.0 gabriele$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup is trying to run the command `gcc-4.2`, which doesn't seem to exist on your system. Verify by running `which gcc-4.2` or `locate gcc-4.2` (you may need to run `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` before you can use the latter command). In case it doesn't exist, simply create a symlink in the same directory in which the `gcc` binary resides:

```
cd $(dirname $(which gcc))
sudo ln -s gcc gcc-4.2
```

Comment: Ummm... yes. You did notice the *second half* of my answer, didn't you?

Comment: Actually gcc-4.2 seems to be ok.. any idea??? 

[I need bitarray because requested by [peach](http://code.google.com/p/peach/), a python package I need to implement the fuzzy-c-means algorithm. If you know any other usefull Python-tool for my goal it would be great! ] 

Last login: Mon Sep 10 14:31:37 on ttys000
MacBook-Pro-di-Gabriele:~ gabriele$ which gcc-4.2
MacBook-Pro-di-Gabriele:~ gabriele$ 
MacBook-Pro-di-Gabriele:~ gabriele$ gcc -version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
MacBook-Pro-di-Gabriele:~ gabriele$

Comment: IT WORKKKKSSSSSS!!! ;-) tank youuu!!!